# VMware Workstation pro16 で仮想OSが消える

Tags: vmware

ホストOS、Windows11にVMware（有料版）をインストールし
「ubuntu20.04.4 LTS」と「Alma Linux8」を仮想OSとして設定していました。

当初は問題ありませんでした。VMwareを起動すると以下のように設定したOSが表示され
「起動」を押すと問題なく使えていました。

[image: 正常]

ところがここ数日、以下の画像のように設定したOSが表示される。パワーオン出来ません。VMwareを立ち上げると仮想OSを起動する完全に消えています。
自分なりに探してみたのですが見つかりません。

[image: VMware Workstation Pro16]

新規で設定するのにも時間がそれなりにかかりますし困っています。
同じような経験をした方いらっしゃいますか？

もし原因、復旧の仕方などご存じの方いらっしゃいましたら教えて下さい。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: "消えた" というのが、単に GUI 上に表示されないだけなのか、それとも仮想マシンのファイル自体が削除された状態なのかを切り分ける必要があると思います。 - [仮想マシン ファイル | VMware Docs](https://docs.vmware.com/jp/VMware-Workstation-Pro/15.0/com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-A968EF50-BA25-450A-9D1F-F8A9DEE640E7.html)

Comment: ありがとうございます。GUI上に表示されないだけと思います。仮想OSのファイル自体もなくなっているようです。探し方がわかりません。よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VMware Workstation は使用していないので憶測も含みますが、画面を見る限り単にタブを閉じてしまっただけのように見えます。

---

1枚目の画像で下の方に **構成ファイル** という項目がありますが、ここに表示されている `C:\User\<USER>\Documents\Virtual Machines\` の下にゲスト OS ごとのフォルダ / vmx ファイル等が格納されているかをまず確認してください。

ファイルが確認できたら vmx ファイルを VMware から開き、仮想マシンが起動できるか確認してください。

Comment: 該当のパスからvmxファイルをVMwareから開き起動すると先日設定したAlmaLinuxも復活出来ました。「構成ファイル」に目も行きませんでした。本当に助かりました。いつもありがとうございます。